# bioinformatics resources

Tags: blogs, bioinformatics

When is about programming, we certain have some blogs to follow, but when your thinking to try a different field, how can you find the big names?

I wish to try bioinfrmatics field and to add into my daily schedule some blog reads from this domain. Can you recommend me some blogs?

Comment: biotechnology != bioinformatics

Comment: When you Googled, what did you find?  What's wrong with them?  What more do you want?  Do you want comments on the ones you've found?

Comment: @S.Lott: that's not so easy, if you just type 'bioinformatics blog' on google you miss a lot of good sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll bite...

[Bioinformatics Zen](http://www.bioinformaticszen.com/)

[Dienekes' Anthropology Blog](http://dienekes.blogspot.com/)

[john hawks weblog](http://johnhawks.net/)

[MassGenomics](http://www.massgenomics.org/)

[O'Really](http://duncan.hull.name/)

[Open Reading Frame](http://www.sennoma.net/) (stale)

[Public Rambling](http://pbeltrao.blogspot.com/)

[The Loom](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/blog/the-loom/)

[the mind wobbles](http://themindwobbles.wordpress.com/)

[the spittoon](http://blog.23andme.com/)

[Trapped in the USA](http://boscoh.com/)

[What You're Doing Is Rather Desperate](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/)

... in fact any blogs that cover biochemistry, pharmacology, epidemiology,computational intelligence, informatics, statistics, population genetics and others.

Answer (score 6):

[Blue Collar Bioinformatics](http://bcbio.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 4):

- [programming4scientists.com](http://www.programming4scientists.com/) - tricks for scientists entering the world of programming
- [mailund on the Internet](http://www.mailund.dk/) - nice blog on programming, population genetics, simulations
- [Open-Bio news](http://news.open-bio.org/news/) - news from the project that hosts bioperl, biopython, etc..
- [FinchTalk](http://www.geospiza.com/finchtalk/) - this one is from a company, but it is interesting and technical worthy of reading it.
- [Fisheye Perspective](http://www.abhishek-tiwari.com/) - very interesting with news on synthetic biology and else - the author is very active in many bioinformatics communities. note: I suggest you to register to the [feeds](http://feeds2.feedburner.com/AbhishekTiwarisBlog) directly
- [88 Proof Synthetic Biology](http://88proof.com/synthetic_biology/blog)
- [Learning R](http://learnr.wordpress.com/) - as the title says, tips to learn R
- [BioCS](http://blog.mckuhn.de/)
- [MentalIndigestion](http://www.mentalindigestion.net/)
- [PDB - MOlecule of the Month](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/motm.do)
- [The molecule of the Month](http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/motm/motm.htm)  - similar style to pdb's, but different authors

Answer (score 2):

When searchin into a new field I've found clusty.com very valuable. It is a meta search machine that classifies and clusters the results so you can easily get those results covering your interests. This gives a good start and can than be extended via google.
Trying 'bioinformatics' returns 10 clusters, amoung are 'computational' or 'program', but also 'genome', #publishing' or 'articles'.

Just my €0.02!

Answer (score 1):

[Helixsoft, a blog on bioinformatics and open source development](http://www.helixsoft.nl/blog)

Answer (score 1):

you can check out ufumes.blogspot.com for a blog article on bioinformatics. you can also access similar bioresource from http://Nigerianbioscientist.com

Answer (score 0):

And if you care to get a system which provides you with software for your needs:

[image: Debian Med]

Debian has hundreds of related packages thanks to work of Debian Med: e.g. browse through the task pages such as [Next generation sequencing](http://debian-med.alioth.debian.org/tasks/bio-ngs), [Cloud - Debian Med bioinformatics applications usable in cloud computing](http://debian-med.alioth.debian.org/tasks/cloud) , etc at
http://debian-med.alioth.debian.org/tasks/